# Is there a way to pass an argument from NavHostController to ViewModel?

Tags: android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

How can i pass an `argument` from `NavHostController` to my `ViewModel` `init{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand how is the SQL query related here. To pass an argument from your navigation arguments to a viewmodel you have to use SavedStateHandle. Then you can use get() or getLiveData(). The key would be equal to the argument name.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate